# Datepicker date formatting return minute instead of month

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, formatting

```
$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({  format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',  pickTime:false})
```

when I used this code to pick date,it is picking minute instead of month.what might be the reason?

Comment: `mm` is minutes, `MM` is month. [Formats](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use MM:

```
$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({  format: 'dd/MM/yyyy',  pickTime:false})
```

see :[MSDN Documentation on Js date formatting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff743760(v=vs.94).aspx)